# "ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias" i am having this error can anyone tell me what's the problem and its solution

Tags: sql, oracle

this is my sample code;-

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(

ord_no int,
purch_amt float,
ord_date varchar(50),
customer_id int,
salesman_id int,
PRIMARY KEY(ord_no)
);

INSERT INTO orders (ord_no, purch_amt, ord_date, customer_id, salesman_id)
VALUES (70001, 150.5, '2012-10-05', 3005, 5002);

CREATE VIEW totalforday 
 AS SELECT ord_date , COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id),
 AVG(purch_amt), SUM(purch_amt)
 FROM orders
 GROUP BY ord_date;
```

Comment: An Oracle error from MySQL... Replace the <mysql> tag with <oracle>.

Comment: You have to name the select columns in the create view. E.g. `COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) cust_cnt`.

Comment: This is one of Oracle's clearer error messages *8-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine writing a query for your new view.

```
SELECT ord_date,
       COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id),
       AVG(purch_amt),
       SUM(purch_amt)
 FROM totalforday;
```

Your column names - are you asking for a column called SUM(purch_amt), or are you trying to do a sum on a column called purch_amt?

You need to provide a valid column name for the view, either implicitly or explicitly. Adding an alias allows the database to implicitly figure out what to name your column.

Like so.

```
CREATE or replace VIEW totalforday 
 AS SELECT ord_date , COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) how_many_customers,
 AVG(purch_amt) avg_amt, SUM(purch_amt) total_amt
 FROM orders
 GROUP BY ord_date;
```

[image]

Comment: its working but i have doubt that whenever i have to create view it is necessary to do this COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) how_many_customers,
 AVG(purch_amt) avg_amt, SUM(purch_amt) total_amt

Comment: that's a completely different question, and to help you with that, we'd need to know more about the business need behind the requirement of this view you're building

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html#GUID-61D2D2B4-DACC-4C7C-89EB-7E50D9594D30) says:

> If you omit the [view] aliases, then the database derives them from the columns or column aliases in the query. For this reason, you must use aliases if the query contains expressions rather than only column names.

So with your view definition that does not include a column/alias list for the view itself, you have to provide them in the query, as @Jeff showed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW totalforday
AS
SELECT ord_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) AS count_customers,
  AVG(purch_amt) AS avg_purch_amt,
  SUM(purch_amt) AS sum_purch_amt
FROM orders
GROUP BY ord_date;

describe totalforday

Name            Null? Type   
--------------- ----- ------ 
ORD_DATE              DATE   
COUNT_CUSTOMERS       NUMBER 
AVG_PURCH_AMT         NUMBER 
SUM_PURCH_AMT         NUMBER
```

The alternative is to specify the column names for the view explicitly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW totalforday
  (ord_date, count_customers, avg_purch_amt, sum_purch_amt)
AS
SELECT ord_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id),
  AVG(purch_amt),
  SUM(purch_amt)
FROM orders
GROUP BY ord_date;

describe totalforday

Name            Null? Type   
--------------- ----- ------ 
ORD_DATE              DATE   
COUNT_CUSTOMERS       NUMBER 
AVG_PURCH_AMT         NUMBER 
SUM_PURCH_AMT         NUMBER
```

The query can still have aliases for the columns and column expressions as well, which is helpful if you ever want to run that independently, but they are ignored by the view - the explicit names/aliases are still used:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW totalforday
  (ord_date, count_customers, avg_purch_amt, sum_purch_amt)
AS
SELECT ord_date AS ignored_1,
  COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) AS ignored_2,
  AVG(purch_amt) AS ignored_3,
  SUM(purch_amt) AS ignored_4
FROM orders
GROUP BY ord_date;

describe totalforday

Name            Null? Type   
--------------- ----- ------ 
ORD_DATE              DATE   
COUNT_CUSTOMERS       NUMBER 
AVG_PURCH_AMT         NUMBER 
SUM_PURCH_AMT         NUMBER
```